# Grunt Serve:dist - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular, gruntfile

Whenever I serve the output files of grunt serve:dist of my angular project which was made using yeoman, I'm getting a 404 error in the console when I come on index.html.

I had also even change the global path in my Gruntfile.js but still getting encountered by the following errors.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/styles/application.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/styles/application.scss Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/scripts/app.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/scripts/controllers/LayoutCtrl.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/scripts/controllers/SidebarCtrl.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/views/Notification/NotificationCtrl.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/views/News/NewsCtrl.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/styles/application.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://0.0.0.0:9000/styles/application.scss Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is the link of my [Gruntfile.js](https://gist.github.com/yashvekaria/240d5685b3c16634911aa6671a04d1e8)

Comment: I have the exact same problem Did you find a solution? This is extremely annoying as I can not deploy my application.